# Drupal Panels - Write a ctools style plugin for a specific view pane

Tags: drupal, plugins, panels, drupal-ctools

Is it possible to write a ctools style plugin for a specific view pane?
When I try to create a normal style plugin, I want any of my content panes to be able to use it.

Comment: I've the same problem. Any solution?

Comment: I found a smiliar question here: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/125694/how-to-make-a-style-plugin-available-only-for-certain-types-of-panes

Answer (score 0):

From the answer of https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/125694/how-to-make-a-style-plugin-available-only-for-certain-types-of-panes

There's a patch for panels which hopfully makes it way into upstream:
https://www.drupal.org/node/2320045